# Code for sending activation data back to django server from email

Tags: python, django, django-registration, django-email

Im trying to understand the django-registration app, and now Im able to send emails to users with activation key. What Im not able to figure out is how to send the activation key back to server when the user clicks a link in his/her email.

```
class AbstractEmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      .....
       .....
   def send_activation_email(self, email):  
    email = email   
    ctx_dict = { 'activation_key' : self.activation_key,
             'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS,
                                                                }

    subject = render_to_string('activation_email_subject.txt', ctx_dict)
    subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
    message = render_to_string('activation_email.txt', ctx_dict)

    send_mail(subject, message, 'gccFishing.com', [email],  fail_silently = False)

   def activate(self, activation_key):
    if SHA1_RE.search(activation_key):
        try:
        self.get(activation_key = activation_key)
        except:
        self.model.DoesNotExist
        return False
        if not self.activation_key_expired():
        self.is_active = True
        self.activation_key = self.model.ACTIVATED
        self.save()
        return self
    return False
```

What code should go inside `activation_email.txt`  for creating a link that calls the `activate method` with `activation_key` ? 
Or is there a better way of doing it?

Any help will be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your email if you are using the sites django app:

```
http://{{ site.domain }}{% url registration_activate activation_key %}
```

Or else change site.domain with the DNS of your site. your

If I remember correct, django-registration already contains an example activation_email.txt in its templates, check it out.

**Update**

I don't think that you should put the activation login in your User class. You definitely cannot do `{% url user.registration_activate activation_key %}` since you must pass a View to the url template tag! You cannot create a link without a view function (or a CBV).

What you have to do is to create a view that searches the Profiles for the activation_key and activates it. Check the `ActivationView` method of django-registration / registration / backends / default / views.py.

If you want to implement custom logic to your app just sublclass `ActivationView` and use your class in the urls.py instead of the default (django-registration / registration / backends / default / urls.py):
`url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', ActivationView.as_view(), name='registration_activate'),`

Comment: I already checked django-registration but there are no templates, tried looking else where also but no luck. Your answer would work if registration_activate was a function based view, but here its actually a method of a User object and I want do something like this, {% url user.registration_activate activation_key %}. Any ideas?